# Extend either item type or type for items in an array

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I've a function that processes some entities and in the end adds properties to them. It is quite flexible and can work with different types of values: properties can be assigned to the objects or if it's an array, for every object in the array (real stuff is way more complex and can't be splitted into different functions). In the end it extends the incoming type and returns extended one with few properties. So it looks like so:

```js
function addSomeStuff<T>(data): TypeWithAddedProperty<T> {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        return data.map(element => {
            const newElement = { ...element, addedProperty: 'something' }
            return newElement;
        })
    } else {
        const newElement = { ...data, addedProperty: 'something' }
        return newElement;
    }
}
export type TypeWithAddedProperty<T> = T & {addedProperty: string};
```

So the question is: can the `TypeWithAddedProperty` be conditional so it will support array there? Now if I pass an array inside, I'll have `TypeWithAddedProperty<Array<T>>` instead of actual `Array<TypeWithAddedProperty<T>>`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you can achieve what you need with function overloading:

The idea is to define that `addSomeStuff` when given an array returns an array and when given a regular value returns a regular value.

```
function addSomeStuff<T>(data: T[]):TypeWithAddedProperty<T>[];
function addSomeStuff<T>(data: T):TypeWithAddedProperty<T>;

function addSomeStuff<T>(data: T|T[]): TypeWithAddedProperty<T>|TypeWithAddedProperty<T>[] {
    if (isArray(data)) {
        return data.map((element:T) => {
            const newElement = { ...element, addedProperty: 'something' }
            return newElement as TypeWithAddedProperty<T>;
        })
    } else {
        const newElement = { ...data, addedProperty: 'something' }
        return newElement;
    }
}
export type TypeWithAddedProperty<T> = T & {addedProperty: string};



const a : TypeWithAddedProperty<{}> = addSomeStuff({}); // works
const b : TypeWithAddedProperty<{}>[] = addSomeStuff([ {} ]); // works

const c : TypeWithAddedProperty<{}>[] = addSomeStuff({}); // error
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that in a more generic way. First, declare a type that is either `T` or an arbitrary nested array of `T`'s:

```
interface Subtree<T> extends Array<T | Subtree<T>> { }
type Tree<T> = T | Subtree<T>;
```

(see [Describe a deeply nested array in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40602784/describe-a-deeply-nested-array-in-typescript) for details).

Now define a function that accepts `Tree<T>` and a function `T->U` and returns `Tree<U>`:

```
function fmap<T, U>(fn: (arg: T) => U) : (arg: Tree<T>) => Tree<U> {
    return function(x: Tree<T>) {
        if (Array.isArray(x)) {
            return x.map(fmap(fn))
        } else {
            return fn(x)
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can do things like:

```
type Foo = { foo: number };
type FooBar = Foo & { bar: string };

let addBar = fmap((x: Foo) => ({...x, 'bar': 'hey'}));

let data = [{foo: 1}, [{foo: 2}, [{foo: 3}]]];
let res = addBar(data); // checks as Tree<FooBar>
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoFcBGYoQgHgBUA+ZCAD0hABMBnZAQSijgE8jkAfNLHPI4qQDeAXwBQYsKwAOKQrgIlkAXmSEuPbAoEBuCTHQgEYYAHsQyGAFs40ogBpkAVWIAKGCABcyV3CgBzb0IAShVSJ2DvXwCg7RJQ5VJ5fhdkITFkTORcMHQoCwMjE3Mfclj+eLSMrJrgGB8mFlYAOmBaRrZXcmDQ9Jr+rJy8i3Jmm2l3cfcQHuqBkTIAG1oUPoH+ofzLEC7guf7xGvFxSRkUADFTUxU0yyvvEHQrTGhkET0pWWRL0wAhPxuP2QADJbpg-N5aDhQP43noxIsIGBkHBqNR-lAbtZbK4ut4fglSK4hM1SeRHABycFQCneCkACwgrApIh68MRyOocDAcBuAG0hDB7sgAIwiRwCoWmbwAJnFyElwoAzCIALrqvQc7IQeiqVHovyuLk84LwhDmWimRHNRamfyuABSqAA8gA5ZpQqAwuqsVy4WhsiRAA)